# Fragment UDP/TCP segments in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, fragment

I have to measure the speed of UDP and TCP between a Client and a Server, for a university project, and for that we have to choose the data we will send. For example 500 bytes, 750 bytes, 1500 bytes...

In Linux I know how to reduce or increment MTU of the segment, but I do not know how to do it in Java for my application. Are there any function to do it, or a way to make the socket bigger or smaller and force it to send the amount of data that I want?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The MTU is a maximum size, not a minimum. Why not increase it to 9000 byte and only send the size of data you want. (And turn Nagle off)

Comment: But how can I do it @PeterLawrey ?

Comment: You set the maximum MTU in your OS. It's a system wide property.  Then to send less data, you write a smaller amount and turn Nagle off so it is sent immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The Java socket API is pretty high level and doesn't give you much fine grained control.
That said you can write x number of bytes to the socket then flush it.
You should also enable TCP_NODELAY, otherwise the packets may end up being buffered.
So long as the amount of bytes is less than the underlying OS MTU then the messages should be sent in separate packets.